# Wifi access point with two VLANs - How to prevent cross communication between VLANs

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, switch

I have a small network and have a separate network for quests/IOT (VLAN 2), and a main VLAN (VLAN 1).

I want to restrict access between the two VLANs for security reasons.

My current setup (shown below) is not preventing this. The WIFI access point is connected with one cable to the switch. So both VLANs are present on the access point.

I have tested with ARP spoofing on VLAN 1 and got network traffic from VLAN 2.
VLAN 2 has device isolation enabled, which does restrict it. But is not enough I think.

I would like to have zero connection between the two VLANs and prevent VLAN hopping.

How would I do this?
I was thinking that maybe a managed switch could work here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's for security reasons, then you *must* use a managed switch – so that you could tell it which ports are allowed to use which VLAN IDs. That's part of why it's "managed".

(Though note that a switch being "managed" doesn't actually *imply* it'll have VLAN support – you still have to specifically look for **802.1Q VLAN** support in its specification)

Unless explicitly configured, a switch knows nothing about which ports are connected to what – it doesn't have any special treatment for 'router' ports vs 'computer' ports, and it doesn't know which ports are supposed to receive VLAN 2 tagged packets and which ports aren't. If one of your PCs decides to generate packets with VLAN ID 2 tag, the switch will allow them.

> VLAN 2 has device isolation enabled, which does restrict it.

No, it only has device isolation enabled on *some* bridges – but such settings don't automatically propagate across the entire network, they're only enforced on the same device. Your Wi-Fi access point might enforce isolation between *its* "Wifi 2" clients, but the unmanaged switch does not.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. One question, because my WIFI access point has two VLANs and SSIDs with only one cable connection to the switch. Does a managed switch work for that?

Comment: Yes, as far as VLANs go it's the exact same configuration as for the router (which also has two VLANs and one cable connection). Depending on manufacturer, multi-VLAN ports might be called "trunk" mode (vs "access" ports that are single-VLAN), or they might simply have multiple tagged VLANs assigned (without any explicit "mode" selection).

Comment: Thanks for the fast response and good explanation